# Disable aggregate for sbt custom task

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I disable aggregate for a single custom task?

I tried to add the following to my `build.sbt`:

```
aggregate in myTaskName:= false
```

But it doesn't work as I expected - I've got this error:

```
~\build.sbt:1: error: not found: value myTaskName
aggregate in myTaskName:= false
```

Comment: Where is `myTaskName` defined?

Comment: @MarkHarrah Actually in custom plugin, but I tried to define it in the project and got the same error

Comment: The `build.sbt` file is Scala code.  It does import some things automatically, but the identifier must be in scope.  So, if you have `org.example.MyClass.myTaskName`, you'd need to import or fully qualify `myTaskName`.

Answer (score 4):

Working example (sbt 0.13.5):

```
val hello = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "Prints 'Hello Zhu'")

val helloTask = hello := {
  println("Hello Zhu")
}

aggregate in hello := false
```

Note, that `TaskKey` was used - not the `Setting[Task]` itself. It worth additional notice that this key should be accessable from your `build.sbt` and, as @Mark Harrah mentioned, `hello` must be fully-qualified.