# Is there a way in sbt to only aggregate specific tasks?

Tags: sbt

My build consists of a root project, sub projects, and other meta projects. The sub projects produce a JAR while the meta projects are for other things like packaging etc.

See [Cross platform build with SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071612/cross-platform-build-with-sbt) for the reason why I am doing this. For now assume this the right thing to do, but if not then feel free to comment on that question.

What I want to be able to do is to aggregate all my sub projects like so:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(subProjects: _*)

val subProjects = Seq(projectA, projectB)

lazy val projectA = project
lazy val projectB = project
```

For the packaging I have something like:

```
lazy val packaging = (project in file("packaging").
  enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging). // Using sbt-native-packager
  settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(projectA.projectID, projectB.projectID)
  )
```

Now before packaging I have to publish the sub projects:

```
sbt> publishLocal
```

And then to package from those published artifacts I do:

```
sbt> packaging/universal:packageBin
```

This all works great but now for the real question, how can I aggregate specific tasks? For example I want to be able to clean all projects including the packaging one.

I know that it is possible to do the opposite, see [Disable aggregate for sbt custom task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323038/disable-aggregate-for-sbt-custom-task).

I've had a bit of a look at sbt.Aggregation but I can't make head or tail of it.

My ideal solution would look something like:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(subProjects: _*).
  settings(aggregatedTasks(metaTasks, metaProjects ): _*)

...

val metaProjects = Seq(packaging, someOtherProject)

val metaTasks = Seq(clean, someOtherTask)

def aggregatedTasks(tasks: Seq[TaskKey[_]], projects: Seq[Project]): Seq[Setting[_]] = {
  ??? // Is there a way to do this?
}
```